# Guest account issue

Tags: discussion

So I'm having this major issue. Before I had an account on arqade I posted a question [Is it possible to make a moving platform below a player's feet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257057/is-it-possible-to-make-a-moving-platform-below-a-players-feet). then like 5 minutes later I decided I should just get an account. later on the question I posted as a guest people started to ask questions with comments and since I just got an account I don't have 50 rep so I can't comment back. so how do I reply to their comments. can you give me answer fast cuz the people are getting ticked off that I'm not replying.

Comment: can you add a link to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Please read https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Your "guest" post is actually owned by a separate account than the registered account you're using. You can see the page for that account by clicking on the username that shows below that post. What you want is merging that account with yours.

Comment: i have read this but this is not what my question is asking. i only have one account but i want to post comments on the question i posted as a guest

Comment: @gamer103 sorry, please see my edit, hopefully that helps explain what's going on

Comment: ya. sorry to. i don't think my question was clear enough